# cmd mysqldump using c

Tags: c, cmd, mysql

I wanted to backup mysql db using a c program,here is what I came up with:

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <stdlib.h>
     main(){
      system("D:\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe dbname -u root -p > C:\db_backup.sql");
     }
```

It says "***D:mysql is not recognized as an internal or external command.***"

But when I tried it entered "D:\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe dbname -u root -p > C:\db_backup.sql in cmd(with admin rights) it worked.

And also how do I execute that cmd command with admin rights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a C string, the backslash is a meta character that indicates something different about whatever character follows. The most obvious example is `\n`, which is replaced with a carriage return.

When you truly wish to have a backslash in your string, you must specify `\\`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that C interprets \ as an escape sequence, so you have to replace all \s in strings in C with `\\`s.

(It's the same in other C-based programming languages.)